# How can I modify the result of the core Path listing filter?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

The core Path module defines the page `admin/config/search/path` which gives a listing of all path aliases.

The menu hook in the module calls the `path_admin_overview` function in `path.admin.inc` which makes the query to retrieve a list of URL aliases:

```
$query->condition('alias', '%' . preg_replace('!\*+!', '%', $keys) . '%', 'LIKE');
```

What I would like to do is somehow intercept this query and modify the condition in a custom module (to avoid hacking core, of course). **To be more precise, I want to make it possible to extend the condition to search the `source` column as well as the `alias` column as indicated above.**

My first thought was to intercept the Path admin listing form: `path_admin_filter_form` which I have done using `hook_form_alter`. I was then hoping that somehow I could override the existing submit handler or attach an second one which would call `path_admin_overview`, but of course I cannot directly modify that core function.

So it seems like I would have to make my own custom copy of `path_admin_overview` and modify the code inside, then have that called instead. Of course this doesn't feel right either - since if the Path module changes, the module will fall behind.

Is there some kind of hook or pattern I can employ here to modify the query in `path_admin_overview` or otherwise achieve the goal indicated in bold in a standalone module?

EDIT: It looks like it could be possible if the query in `path_admin_overview` was tagged (it isn't currently), see here: https://www.drupal.org/node/310077#hook_query_alter

Comment: Have you tried the tag and hook_query_alter apporach? I think it might works, I was about to answer that until I saw your edit.

Comment: Alas, there is no tag for this query. I will see if I can request it - but I'm still open to other approaches for solving the goal in bold if you have any ideas!

Comment: Yes, you're right, query must have a tag or you can't get it on that hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `admin/config/search/path` path using [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)
and use a custom function as menu callback.

```
function oyurmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/config/search/path']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_custom_path_admin_overview'; 
}
```

Then your `mymodule_custom_path_admin_overview` shoud be a copy of `path_admin_overview` with your needed alterations.

This is not optimal as you should keep your function code in sync with original code, so any patches applied to `path_admin_overview`function should applied to your altered function, but is the only way you can alter the functionality without hacking core.